# This app is not allowed to query for scheme kindle

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, bitcode

i'm trying to run my app from my device (iphone 5) but i get this issue, someone can tell me what i've to do to make it right?

ld: '/Users/...../Documents/Myapp.spritebuilder/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureIdUtil.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

Comment: What does the question's title have to do with the error message you posted? They are two completely separate issues.

Comment: duplicate in terms of question body, the question title is just a big `?`!

Comment: i copy the errore in the debug

Comment: look at the question I linked. it is the exact same issue.

Comment: goto build settings. type bit code.. make that No and rebuild